# pipenv install: the environment variable LANG is not set

Tags: macos, pipenv, virtual-environment

I changed my laptop with window process to macOS and I installed some development tools and virtual environment tools.

Now I get this error message while installing pipenv

`the environment variable LANG is not set!`

I did googling and many peoples tell that I have to edit some part in 'profile'.

I'd like to know exactly what do I have to edit in this file and also I'd like to know if that change is valid for macOS.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49436922/2096221). The answer is that you'll need to add some environment variables in your Shell profile or rc file. Hope this helps!

Comment: Also here's [the official documentation on the error](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/diagnose/#valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8) and how to fix it.